# LTS 20.04.02 Software Update Question

Tags: 20.04, updates, update-manager, lts

Logged in to 20.04 and a screen appeared 'distribution update' which I clicked (I'm only on LTS updates so not sure why this came up). I was on 20.04 and still on 20.04 so I presume this might be a point update to 20.04. When I tried to update after it said could not load repository information. Upon looking it said 'The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily Release' no longer has a Release file.' As such I deleted this update path.
I left the remaining ones in below and tried to remove anything from Wily/Bionic. My question is - the update paths in the image, are these all the ones I need or should I add (or remove) anything else for 20.04?
Thanks

[image: sudo apt-get update]

Comment: It is preferred to add textual output as text in your message (formatted as code) and not as a screendump.

Comment: Thanks, yes these links answer my question. The sources I have in place for updates seem inline with others on here so I'm happy. I just have to remove any outdated ones.

Answer (score 4):

These are my Focal Fossa ( Ubuntu 20.x LTS ) Sources;

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted

deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe

deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```